# Segfault after fread() call

Tags: c++, gcc, file-io, fread

I have the following code:

```
char*
Sender::PrepareData(char* filename, unsigned long long int bytesToTransfer)
{
    FILE* dataFile = fopen(filename, "rb"); 
    if (dataFile==NULL) {fputs ("File error",stderr); exit (1);}

    cout << "File Open: " << filename << endl;

    char* theData;
    size_t bytesRead = fread(&theData, 1, bytesToTransfer, dataFile);
    if (bytesRead != bytesToTransfer) {fputs ("Reading error",stderr); exit (3);}

    cout << "Data Read -- Num Bytes: " << bytesRead << endl;
    cout << "Data to Send: " << *theData << endl;

    return theData;
}
```

When this method gets hit, my output is:

> File Open: t.bin
>
> Data Read -- Num Bytes: 10
>
> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

My `t.bin` file contains the following:

> This is a test.
>
> 98172398172837129837
>
> alsjdf89u32ijofiou2
>
> TEST TEST...
>
> !!## TESTING TEST!! ###(DLKAJ)

When I run through gdb, the segfault output is:

```
File Open: t.bin Data Read -- Num Bytes: 10

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 0x00000000004015e2 in Sender::PrepareData (this=0x603010, filename=0x7fffffffe363 "t.bin", bytesToTransfer=10)
    at sender.cpp:98  98        cout << "Data to Send: " << *theData << endl;
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: cout << "Data to Send: " << *theData << endl; here check for the value of the thedata.It might be null value..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a buffer, `theData` is just a pointer.

Something like

```
char theData[1000];
size_t bytesRead = fread(theData, 1, bytesToTransfer, dataFile);
```

might work depending on the maximum value of `bytesToTransfer`

If you are sure you are reading a string you might also need to terminate `theData` before writing to `cout`,

```
theData[bytesRead] = '\0';
```

You'll need to allocate your buffer on the heap if you want to return it.

It'd be a lot easier to do something like

```
std::vector<char>
PrepareData(char* filename, unsigned long long int bytesToTransfer)
{
  std::ifstream file(filename, file.binary);

  if (!file) {
    std::cerr << "File error";
    exit(1);
  }

  std::cout << "File Open: " << filename << '\n';

  std::vector<char> data(bytesToTransfer + 1);
  file.read(data.data(), bytesToTransfer);
  data.back() = '\0';

  if (!file) {
    std::cerr << "Reading error";
    exit(3);
  }

  std::cout << "Data Read -- Num Bytes: " << bytesToTransfer << '\n';
  std::cout << "Data to Send: " << data.data() << '\n';
  return data;
}
```

Then again if all you are doing is reading `char`s from a file you should probably consider using `string`s.

Comment: Why does [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/) use `char * buffer`?

Comment: @MrDuk You missed a step `buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*lSize);`

Comment: I changed my code to `theData = (char*) malloc (bytesToTransfer);`, but I still get segfaults in the same spot.

Comment: @MrDuk - "how could I allocate just the amount needed"... Use a `vector` or a `string` (or an `auto_ptr`). While you are at it, use an `ifstream` rather than `FILE*`.

Comment: @jww the data is being sent over a UDP socket -- so I think sticking with `char*` is the simpler option here, no?

Comment: @MrDuk - in that case, `mmap` it and avoid the allocation and/or copy altogether.

Comment: @MrDuk Are you sure you have changed `fread(&theData` to `fread(theData` ? Either way you should think about returning a `vector` instead, see my edit.

Comment: @jww heyoo, Beej even has [a guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/mmap.html) for using `mmap` - thanks